# Bad power consumption on Lenovo ideapad Y700 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, power-management, lenovo, battery

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my new Lenovo Y700 and I was very surprised that the battery work less than 2 hours, when the specification says that can until 5 hours. I switched to Windows to test it and on Windows 10 it works as the specification says.

Someone can help me? what information shall I pick up from my computer to investigate more about this issue and to resolve it?

Here I attach a result of using top to look which processes are using the CPU:

```
top - 20:22:04 up 36 min,  1 user,  load average: 0,14, 0,22, 0,34
Tasks: 231 total,   2 running, 229 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 22,2 us,  5,6 sy,  0,0 ni, 72,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  7101540 total,  4760072 free,  1636476 used,   704992 buff/cache
top - 20:23:30 up 37 min,  1 user,  load average: 0,34, 0,24, 0,33
Tasks: 233 total,   2 running, 231 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,8 us,  0,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 97,4 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  7101540 total,  4575776 free,  1722336 used,   803428 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  7298044 total,  7298044 free,        0 used.  5060076 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                   
  947 root      20   0  300744  87584  62284 S   6,6  1,2   2:27.70 Xorg                                                      
 2204 jesuspe+  20   0 2092792 1,043g 152236 S   4,0 15,4   9:11.22 firefox                                                   
 1817 jesuspe+  20   0 1159540 110168  72852 S   3,0  1,6   1:00.83 compiz                                                    
 2378 jesuspe+  20   0  657256  36424  28516 S   2,3  0,5   0:03.54 gnome-terminal-                                           
  693 root      20   0    4396   1264   1176 S   1,0  0,0   0:07.99 acpid                                                     
   32 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0,7  0,0   0:00.84 khugepaged                                                
 2736 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   0,7  0,0   0:04.19 kworker/2:1                                               
 2926 jesuspe+  20   0   43436   4004   3300 R   0,7  0,1   0:00.71 top                                                       
 1622 jesuspe+  20   0  359964   8736   7048 S   0,3  0,1   0:07.36 ibus-daemon                                               
 2821 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:02.36 kworker/1:2                                               
 2852 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:03.22 kworker/u8:0                                              
    1 root      20   0  119996   6108   3932 S   0,0  0,1   0:01.97 systemd
```

**graphical configuration:**

```
lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Carrizo
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:37 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:d0800000-d0ffffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:d1500000-d153ffff memory:d1580000-d159ffff
```

**Technical Details**

```
 Brand  Lenovo
    Series  Y700-15ACZ
    Screen Size 15.6 inches
    Processor Brand AMD
    Processor Type  A Series
    Processor Speed 2.1 GHz
    RAM Size    8 GB
    Hard Drive Size 256 GB
    Hard Disk Description   SSD
    Graphics Card Description   Radeon R7+AMD Strato XT, 2GB
    Average Battery Life    5 hours
    Lithium Battery Energy Content  50 Watt Hours
```

Comment: The graphics processor is most likely what's sucking your battery.

Comment: What graphics driver are you using?  Also, check out [this question about general power-saving tips](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter).